# Change textarea cursor color in the textarea

Tags: css, textarea

I have the following textarea:

[image: Textarea example]

How can I change the inner cursor color?

Comment: I dont know. Might be there is no way since cursor is not part of web page but part of OS and each OS will define look and colour of standard cursor

Comment: Here is a link that will answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092963/can-i-change-the-blinking-caret-in-a-form-text-area-in-a-browser

Comment: You should read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret . Just to help in your search, it is `caret` and not cursor. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old and out of date. But the question remains unanswered. Let's fix it.

[Сaret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) is probably what you were looking for.

```css
textarea{
caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

A custom caret can be used with either an .ani or .cur file

```
textarea {
 cursor: url(cursor.cur);
}
```

or

```
textarea {
 cursor: url(cursor.ani);
}
```

For more details regarding [carets](http://www.css3.com/css-cursor/)

or

```
.cursor { font-size: 12px; background-color: red; color: red; position: relative; opacity: 0.5; }
```